# How to compile a bunch of ".java" files in just one command?

Tags: java

**Need a help**.

Iam trying to edit the source of an apk.

I unpacked that apk using apktool then convert that **"classes.dex"** file into **".jar"** using *dex2jar* and then open that **.jar** file in `jd-gui` to save all the sources now all the sources have saved in different different folders containing **".java"** files.

Now my problem is that when ever I am trying to compile a single **.java** file using `javac` it's shows error: *the specified module is not found*. But that module is there in that same folder. I also tried `eclipse` but it shows that same error.

Is there any way to compile all that folders containing **.java** file back to **"classes.dex"** using one compilation command. Or is there any tools for compilation?

Answer (score 1):

In the folder where all the .java files are that you want compiled, run `javac *.java` then `java *`.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I also tried this command "javac *.java" the same error shows. Do you know any tools or a software for compilation?